# Does second conditions check, if first condition found false in multiple AND-Conditions for a record in SQL?

Tags: sql

if we have multiple AND conditions in where clause of a SQL query and if first condition found false for a records then will it goes to check for another AND condition or not.

in programming we use && operator to check the multiple condition where if first condition found false then it does't goes for another condition, So my query is is it also applies in SQL conditions?

Example:

```
Select * from tablename where column is not null and column > 0 and column <> 1
```

Comment: why my answer is downvote? is it false?

Comment: @ersin it does not answer the question

Comment: @Bee157 exactly it is the answer

Comment: i didnt downvote your answer and yes this it not what i am asking above, i am upvoting your answer.

Comment: You say "in programming..." as if a) writing SQL *isn't* programming (it is) and b) Short-circuit evaluation is *universal* to all other prgramming languages (it isn't)

Comment: multiple where statements are optimized, and during execution MySQL stops when 1 is found false. I'm looking for  a reference.

Comment: @PraveenRawat you sayed : **Does second conditions check, if first condition found false in multiple AND-Conditions ** so it must be

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436469/does-order-of-where-clauses-matter-in-sql Simply put query optimizer is free to check conditions in any order. It will stop checking other conditions when it finds first FALSE, but the order of evaluation is unpredictable

Comment: @Bee157, but you don't know in which order the conditions are evaluated.

Comment: This depends highly on the DBMS used. Detecting conditions that can never true is the job of the query optimizer. I would say most modern optimizers would catch the situation that the condition `column is not null` is redundant in your query. But in general SQL usually doesn't short-circuit conditions.

Comment: The real question is: why do you care?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL is declarative. Not procedural.

The optimiser may use short circuit evaluation or may not.

It also may convert that to something different. If `column` is integer type all three conditions collapse to

```
WHERE column > 1
```

Similarly the optimiser might find some conditions are guaranteed to be true or false by check constraints or other predicates in the query and don't need evaluating at all. Or use an access path (such as filtered index) that guarantees all rows match a part of the predicate so no run time evaluation is needed.

Comment: if the column has - values ?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar - they are excluded by `column > 0 ` in the question.

Answer (score -3):

It will looks like this

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 

WHERE (column != null AND column  <> 1) AND (column   > 0)
```