# Why Django ignores the order of conditions in filter()?

Tags: python, django

When filtering multiple conditions with Django queryset filter(), the order of conditions in filter() is not guaranteed.

Especially when I filter date/datetime fields, they're filtered at the last in the WHERE clause.

These two querysets generate the same SQL with the same WHERE clause.

```py
dt = datetime(2022, 1, 1)
User.objects.filter(joined_at__lt=dt, is_active=True)
User.objects.filter(is_active=True, joined_at__lt=dt)
```

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE (`user`.`is_active` = 1 AND `user`.`joined_at` < '2022-01-01 00:00:00')
```

I know I can fix this problem with chaining filters.

But I'm wondering why Django ignores the order of conditions in filter().
And what is the rule for Django to decide the order in the filter()?

===============

The order of conditions in the WHERE clause affects the database execution plan. I want to fix the first column in the WHERE clause to prevent the FULL TABLE SCAN.

If I add a single index on `joined_at` field, this query will be executed with a FULL TABLE SCAN.

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE (`user`.`is_active` = 1 AND `user`.`joined_at` < '2022-01-01 00:00:00')
```

But if I run this query, the index will be used.

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE (`user`.`joined_at` < '2022-01-01 00:00:00' AND `user`.`is_active` = 1)
```

They're not equivalent.

======================

I had a misunderstanding about the index and optimizer.

It is written in one of my old database books that the order of conditions matters for a database execution plan.

But when I tested with MySQL 5.7 and 8.0, both of the queries were executed in the same plan INDEX RANGE SCAN.

Database optimizer is clever enough to decide which condition should be executed first for better performance.

See also: [Does the order of where clauses matter in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436469/does-the-order-of-where-clauses-matter-in-sql)

Comment: Exactly _what_ is the problem? The order of conditions in SQL does not matter.

Comment: Why do you care about the order of the WHERE clauses in the generated SQL?

Comment: The order of conditions in the WHERE clause affects the database execution plan. I want to fix the first column in the WHERE clause to prevent the FULL TABLE SCAN.

Comment: There is no such specific rule in django for ordering and it's not very necessary to maintain order, but django provides `order_by('fieldname')`.

Comment: @qu3vipon which DB are you using? Most DBs will optimise the query which should mean the order of clauses won't matter

Comment: Can you add the output of `EXPLAIN` for both your queries?