# Power Query Conditional JOIN - JOIN with WHERE clause

Tags: join, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

How to join two tables with a condition?

TABLE A

| from | to | commission |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 12/08/2021 | 0,2 |
| 13/08/2021 | 31/12/2021 | 0,3 |

TABLE B

| date | client | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 07/03/2021 | Client A | 23 € |
| 08/05/2021 | Client B | 32 € |
| 14/09/2021 | Client C | 44 € |

EXPECTED OUTPUT

| date | client | price | commission |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/03/2021 | Client A | 23 € | 0,2 |
| 08/05/2021 | Client B | 32 € | 0,2 |
| 14/09/2021 | Client C | 44 € | 0,3 |

I want to add the COMMISSION that applies to a sell depending on the DATE of the sell. I should join the two tables on "TABLE A"[FROM DATE] < "TABLE B"[DATE] AND "TABLE B"[DATE] < "TABLE A"[TO DATE].

I do not want to join every register in both tables and check that condition after the join. I want to check the condition on the join itself.

Comment: Please provide some sample data that can be copied along with expected output.

Comment: What is stopping you? Where are you stuck? What part are you able to do? [mre] What do "check that condition after the join" & "check the condition on the join itself" mean? WHERE VS ON? Why do you want that? Why do you care? It doesn't matter how ANDed conditions are distributed over ON & WHERE for an inner join, it is trivial for the DBMS to rearrange to the same best implemenation.

Comment: Add it to your question and format it properly. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post

Comment: @philipxy I usually join the two tables "all to all" (for each line in table A a whole set of table B lines are registered in the output table). After that I check if the condition matches for each line and I filter by the ones that do. That is extremely unefficient, and as far as aI am concerned the DBMS doesnt rearrange that specific case, right? I am able to achieve that behaviour, but I guess that way of operating is not efficient. The problem is that it seems that there is no way to join with a where (or on) clause (in that case the DBMS do rearrange the query, right? Thank you!!

Comment: [Inner join vs Where](https://stackoverflow.com/q/121631/3404097) [Execution order of conditions in SQL 'where' clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/340139/3404097) [SQL - Does the order of WHERE conditions matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3152182/3404097) [Order Of Execution of the SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4596739/3404097) etc

Comment: Please if you are giving code manipulating tables ([mre]) give input tables as initialization code in columns & output as text given. (Rather than using post editor table format.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjDXNzDWNzIwMlRQ0lFyzslMzStRcASxjYwVHjWtUYrVASqy0DcwRVfkBGIbG8EVGZroG1iiK3IGsU1MIIpiAQ==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [date = _t, client = _t, price = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"date", type date}, {"client", type text}, {"price", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", (x)=> Table.SelectRows(TableA, (y)=>  x[date] >= y[from] and x[date] < y[to] )),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"commission"}, {"commission"})
in
    #"Expanded Custom"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Commison % =
VAR _date =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table B'[date ] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        FIRSTNONBLANK ( 'Table A'[commission], 1 ),
        _date >= 'Table A'[from ]
            && _date <= 'Table A'[to ]
    )
```

[image: commision]

Comment: PQ is part of PBI.

Comment: I am looking for a power query solution, but not a dax solution. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: @mikizas do not tag powerbi next time...